# How to make a general wpf mvvm window open/close eventhandler?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling

This is my current App.xaml.cs

Its looks simple for one or two, but I have 7-8 windows.
Is there a clever way to make this a little more general and better?

```cs
public App()
{
    _ViewModel = new MyAppViewModel();

    _ViewModel.OpenXXXWindowEvent += new EventHandler(ViewModel_OpenXXXWindow);
    _ViewModel.OpenYYYWindowEvent += new EventHandler(ViewModel_OpenYYYWindow);
    ...
}

private void ViewModel_OpenXXXWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _XXXWindow = new XXXWindow();
    _XXXWindow.DataContext = _ViewModel;
    _XXXWindow.ShowDialog();
}

private void ViewModel_CloseXXXWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_XXXWindow != null)
        _XXXWindow.Close();
}

private void ViewModel_OpenYYYWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _YYYWindow = new YYYWindow();
    _YYYWindow.DataContext = _ViewModel;
    _YYYWindow.ShowDialog();
}

private void ViewModel_CloseYYYWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_YYYWindow != null)
        _YYYWindow.Close();
}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much XAML code-behind is a signal that you're somehow breaking the MVVM pattern. A ViewModel receiving EventArgs is a no-no too.

To open/close dialogs I tend to use a messaging system, for example, the one provided by [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

With a messaging system (using MVVM Light) you do something like this:

In your ViewModel:

```cs
private void SomeMethodThatNeedsToOpenADialog()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send(new OpenDialogXMessage());
}
```

And in your View:

```cs
Messenger.Default.Register<OpenDialogXMessage>(this, (msg) => {

    new DialogX().ShowDialog();
});
```

Some relevant links:

- [How to open a new window using MVVM Light Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386349/how-to-open-a-new-window-using-mvvm-light-toolkit)
- [Show dialog with MVVM Light toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644459/show-dialog-with-mvvm-light-toolkit)

Comment: +1 for the Messaging system approach, although I use [a simplified version of Prism's EventAggregator](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/) instead of MVVM light. The concept is the same - broadcast Messages from any ViewModel, and have your `App` class subscribe to receive those Messages and open/close the window specified in the Message properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not a event handler solution, but how about a `Binding` solution? Unfortunately, you cannot bind `Window.DialogResult`, which causes the window to close, when the value is set. But you could create an `AttachedProperty` which can be bound to a property on the underlying `ViewModel` and sets the not bindable property, when its value is set. The `AttachedProperty` looks like this.

```cs
    public class AttachedProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogResultProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DialogResult", typeof (bool?), typeof (AttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool?), OnDialogResultChanged));

        private static void OnDialogResultChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var wnd = d as Window;
            if (wnd == null)
                return;

            wnd.DialogResult = (bool?) e.NewValue; //here the not bindable property is set and the windows is closed
        }

        public static bool? GetDialogResult(DependencyObject dp)
        {
            if (dp == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dp");

            return (bool?)dp.GetValue(DialogResultProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDialogResult(DependencyObject dp, object value)
        {
            if (dp == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dp");

            dp.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

The `AttachedProperty` can be used like this

```
<Window x:Class="AC.Frontend.Controls.DialogControl.Dialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:hlp="clr-namespace:AC.Frontend.Helper"
        hlp:AttachedProperties.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}">
  <!-- put your content here -->
</Window>
```

Now you can use a `Command` to set the `DialogResult` property of the VM, which is the `DataContext` of the `Window`.