# Open new form and hide this form in mvvm light toolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a LoginWindows, that run in startup.

I have a enterButton ,when click it, send a parametr to mainwindows and  show it then hide self.

```
   public RelayCommand EnterCommand { get; set; }
   ...
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        EnterCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Enter());

    }

    private object Enter()
    {
     //Show MainWndow
     }
```

What is the best way to open a new window from the viewmodel in mvvmLight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Useful answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994523/970404

Concepts:

- Registering Multiple VM's with the SimpleIoC and using
  GetInstance(...) to request them out.
- Messenger class usage with a custom message type OpenWindowMessage
- Opening Modal / Non Modal
  Windows from a parent VM staying true to the MVVM principles
- Passing
  data between windows(just shown in NonModal)

**Important Note:**

The method used in this example to set the non DP DialogResult from the modal window is not MVVM friendly cos it uses code-behind to set the DialogResult property on a Window.Closing event which should be avoided(If needing to be "testable"). My preferred approach is a bit long and is very well documented HERE(Mixture of question and answer). Hence why I ignored it for the sake of this sample.