# Open/Close View from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have an AddClientViewModel which is referenced by 2 views (AddClientView and SuggestedAddressesView). The AddClientView is a form which has a field for an address. The form has a validate button which validates the entered address using Geocoding. If more than one address is returned, the SuggestedAddressesView opens.

Here is how I am currently doing it:

AddClientViewModel:

```
    private void ValidateExecute(object obj)
    {
        SuggestedAddresses = new ObservableCollection<DBHelper.GeocodeService.GeocodeResult>(GeoCodeTest.SuggestedAddress(FormattedAddress));

        ....

        if (SuggestedAddresses.Count > 0)
        {
            var window = new SuggestedAddressesView(this);
            window.DataContext = this;
            window.Show();
        }
    }
```

Here is the SuggestedAddressesView constructor where AddClientViewModel inherits from ViewModelBase

```
    public SuggestedAddressesView(ViewModelBase viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel.ClosingRequest += (sender, e) => this.Close();
    }
```

The other problem I am having is when I call OnClosingRequest() from the AddClientViewModel...both the AddClientView and SuggestedAddressesView closes. I know this happens because both views reference the same ViewModel. This is not the behaviour I want. I would like to be able to independently close either Window.

**Is opening a View from the ViewModel proper MVVM structure and how would I go about being able to close windows independently?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you refer to UI elements(In this case the View) from the VM, you're going against suggested MVVM Guidelines. With just that we can know creating the `Window` object in the VM is wrong.

So now onto rectifying this:

- Firstly try to keep a 1 View <-> 1 VM in your application. It's cleaner and allows you to switch out View implementations with the same logic very easily. Adding multiple View's to the same VM even if not "ground-breaking" just makes it clumsy.
- So now you got `AddClientView` and `SuggestedAddressesView` with their own VM. Great!

Implementing a View Open/Close from the VM:

- Since we cannot access the View directly from our VM(to comply with standards), we can use approaches such as using a `Messenger`(MVVM Light), `EventAggregator`(PRISM) and so on to send a "message" from the VM to the View when you need to open/close a View and do the actual operation in the View.
- This way the VM just initiates the message and can be unit-tested fine for the same operation and does not reference any UI elements.

Using a "Messenger" approach to handle View **open**:

- As per your Logic, it is the `AddClientViewModel` which would have to ask for the `SuggestedAddressesView` to be opened.
- Thus when you detect `SuggestedAddresses.Count > 0`, you would send a message to the `AddClientView` asking it to open up the `SuggestedAddressesView`.
- In `AddClientView.xaml.cs` upon receiving this message, you would do what you're currently doing in the VM. Create an object of `SuggestedAddressesView` and call `.Show()`  on it.
- One extra step you would add in the above step's process is to assign the `DataContext` of `SuggestedAddressesView` as `SuggestedAddressesViewModel`.

That's it. Now what you have is, when `AddClientViewModel` wants `SuggestedAddressesView` shown, it sends a message to it's own View and the View in-turn creates and shows the `SuggestedAddressesView`. This way the VM does not reference any View's and we keep to holding MVVM standards.

Using a "Messenger" approach to handle View **close**:

- Closing a `View` is pretty simple. Again when you need to close the View from the VM, you send a message to it's own View asking for it to be closed.
- On receiving this message, the View pretty much closes itself via `.Hide()` / `.Close()` or however else you want to get rid of it.

In this each VM handles it's own View's closing and you don't have any inter-connected dependencies.

You can use [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994523/1834662) as a start point to guide you in handling "messages" for this approach. it has an attached download you can get and see how the `Messenger` works. This is with MVVM Light, if you do not use it or use something else/ your own MVVM implementation, use it as a guide to help get to what you need.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense! 

The issue I am having is that I'd like the information gathered from **SuggestedAddressesView** to be passed to the **AddClientViewModel** (hence why I was using 1 VM for 2 Views). The reason I am doing this is because the Address selected in the **SuggestedAddressesView** is assigned to a Client defined in the **AddClientViewModel**.

Comment: @francisg3 look at the example link I posted. If you get the example there, The second `Window` opened Modal/Non-Modal passes information back to the MainWindow. This is the process you would be using for your requirement too. You'd pretty much use Messenger to send a message(here the message will be the data you want to send from SuggestedAddressViewModel to AddClientViewModel)

Answer (score 0):

you can use RelayCommand so that you send the parameter as follows:

```
Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TestWindow}"
```

By using this you can close the individual views.

Example:

```
public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(OnClose, IsEnable);
        }
    }

public void OnClose(object param)
    {
       AddClientView/SuggestedAddressesView Obj = param as AddClientView/SuggestedAddressesView;
       obj.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To open window from ViewModel:

Create NavigationService.cs class for opening window:
Let NavigationService.cs

Now put following code in that class file.

```
   public void ShowWindow1Screen(Window1ViewModel window1ViewModel)
       {
           Window1= new Window1();
           Window1.DataContext = window1ViewModel;
           Window1.Owner = Window1View;
           Window1.ShowDialog();
       }
```

then.
Create instance of NavigationService.cs class MainWindowViewModel file.
Then

```
Window1ViewModel window1ViewModel = new Vindow1ViewModel();
window1ViewModel.Name = MainWindowTextValue;
NavigationService navigationService = new NavigationService();
navigationService.ShowWindow1Screen(window1ViewModel);
```