# DataTemplate does not refresh after switching to an object of same DataType

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I have following `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentViewModel}">
   <ContentControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FilledContentViewModel}">
         <usercontrols:FilledMainWindow x:Name="MainContent" />
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:EmptyContentViewModel}">
         <!-- todo: Something like a StartPage here -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

This works great until the view model tries to change the `ContentViewModel` property from one `FilledContentViewModel` to a new `FilledContentViewModel`, then the content of the `ContentControl` does not refresh.
If switching from `EmptyContentViewModel` to `FilledContentViewModel` or the other way around, it works.

Of course, just updating everything in the existing `FilledContentViewModel` instead would be one solution. But I think it could get messy quick and that just creating a new `ViewModel` with the right context and switch it would be more elegant.

Does anybody know a way to let the content of the `DataTemplate` refresh?

Comment: You're doing something in the `Loaded` event of the `FilledMainWindow`? Or you're using one-time bindings that you want refreshed?

Comment: @Yeah69 is `FilledMainWindow` data bound and will react accordingly if you change its `DataContext` from one `FilledContentViewModel` to another?

Comment: @Yeah69 when you change `Content` to another `FilledContentViewModel` it will change `DataContext` and re-evaluate `ContentTemplate` and set it again to `DataTemplate` for `FilledContentViewModel` but for WPF it's same template therefore not a change so it will not recreate user control and effectively only its `DataContext` will change. Guessing problem is somewhere here.

Comment: @Brannon I don't use the `Loaded` event of the `FilledMainWindow` and I also don't use one-time bindings anyway in the project of concern.

Comment: @dkozl I don't know. Didn't try it yet. I'll try to change the DataContext of the `FilledMainWindow` directly (not through DataTemplate) and will tell you the result.

Comment: @dkozl This would be my guess, too. I assume that the `ContentControl` just looks up the DataType and if it is still the same and only reacts if the DataType changes, too. In this project the `FilledContentViewModel` gets an ORM mapper class (using Dapper) injected. So, if another database is opened on runtime I thought it would be easier to change the path to the database in the mapper class and inject it into a new `FilledContentViewModel` instead of updating everything in the existing one.

Comment: @dkozl Now, I tested what you have asked by replacing the whole `ContentControl`, which I posted in the question by `<usercontrols:FilledMainWindow DataContext="{Binding ContentViewModel}" x:Name="MainContent" />`. And then the switching of the `FilledContentViewModel` objects worked as intended. The problem is: The DataTemplate for the EmptyContentViewModel, where I want to put something like a start page in future is dismissed now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with the `ContentPresenter` control where I would switch the `Content` to be a new instance of the same view model type and it wasn't refreshing.  I found nearly the identical problem I was running into on social.msdn.microsoft.com and the solution I ended up using was to create a custom `ContentControl` / `ContentPresenter` that was posted as part of the social.msdn.microsoft.com answer:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bc0a0ed-cb98-4863-a09e-5c99d0ddf90e/mvvm-contentcontrols-view-will-not-refresh?forum=wpf

```
public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
   
    public MyContentControl()
    {
        this.ContentTemplateSelector = new MyDataTemplateSelector();
    }


    class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var declaredDataTemplate = FindDeclaredDataTemplate(item, container);
            var wrappedDataTemplate = WrapDataTemplate(declaredDataTemplate);
            return wrappedDataTemplate;
        }

        private static DataTemplate WrapDataTemplate(DataTemplate declaredDataTemplate)
        {
            var frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
            frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, declaredDataTemplate);
            var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            dataTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory;
            return dataTemplate;
        }

        private static DataTemplate FindDeclaredDataTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var dataTemplateKey = new DataTemplateKey(item.GetType());
            var dataTemplate = ((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource(dataTemplateKey) as DataTemplate;
            if (dataTemplate == null)
                throw new Exception("datatemplate not found");
            return dataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```